# How would I properly separate a string into an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist

My program is meant to seperate the string and then put them in to the array. For example if I input the value LONDON I still get back the string [LONDON] not what I wanted which is [L, O, N, D, O, N].

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ArrayList<String> myArrayList =
            new ArrayList<String>();

    System.out.println("\n" +
            "This is the capacity before adding any strings " +
            myArrayList.size());
    System.out.println("\n" +
            "I will now add a string of my name seperated in the " +
            "Array List");

    myArrayList.add("E");
    myArrayList.add("M");
    myArrayList.add("M");
    myArrayList.add("A");
    myArrayList.add("N");
    myArrayList.add("U");
    myArrayList.add("E");
    myArrayList.add("L");

    System.out.println("\n" +
            "Now let us see the size of the Array List now I have" +
            "put in my name " + myArrayList.size());
    System.out.println("\n" +
            "Let us see what the program has put into my Array List " +
            myArrayList);

    System.out.println("\n" +
            "Now input your own strings!");

    ArrayMods arrayMods
            = new ArrayMods();
    while(true) {
        arrayMods.inputToSeparatedArray();

        System.out.println("This is your Array!" +
                arrayMods.putCharString() +
                "Type in your next string!");
    }
}

}
class ArrayMods{
public char[] inputToSeparatedArray(){
    Scanner scanInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    String toBeSeparated;

    toBeSeparated = scanInput.nextLine();

    return toBeSeparated.toCharArray();
}
public ArrayList<String> putCharString() {
    char[] receivingArray = inputToSeparatedArray();
    for (int x = 0; x > receivingArray.length; x++) {
        putCharString().add(String.valueOf(receivingArray[x]));
    }
    List<String> l = Collections.<String>singletonList(String.valueOf(receivingArray));

    return new ArrayList<String>(l);
}
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. In title you claim that you want ArrayList, but in question itself you say "..then put them in to the array". ArrayList is not the same as array. Use [edit] option to clarify expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the only thing you want to do is to output it as you mentioned above:

```
 String myString = "LONDON";
    List<Character> splittedString = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < myString.length(); i++)
        splittedString.add(myString.charAt(i));
    System.out.println(splittedString);
```

If the only thing you want to is to split them and the output does not really matter, you could use the same code but with an char array. The only thing that will happen, is that wen printed, the output will be LONDON instead of L, O, N, D, O, N (as you mentioned above).

You could still use a for or forEach and print it that way.

Comment: ok thx ik my question was not phrased properly sorry

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Character array and iterate or stream over the chars in the string to fill it up like this :

```
String test = "LONDON";
Character[] charObjectArray =
        test.chars().mapToObj(c -> (char)c).toArray(Character[]::new);
```

Also can be done to a List:

```
List<Character> listOfChars = 
        test.chars().mapToObj(c -> (char) c).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
[L, O, N, D, O, N]
```